# I have always incommig data to my kinesis strem

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I have created a kinesis stream with 6 shards. I just run a simple application whihc put two records to my kinesis and the application finished.

The strange thing is that when I go to monitoring page of my kinesis stream I always see incoming data. For example in last hour I have more than 293K incomming records. I dot have any putrecords.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Per the ScreenShot shared, I don't see any incoming data.

It's just showing you the Data point values bases on your mouse tracker.

Refer the Get Record (Count) - Sum Graph, it shows that no record was Read (GET/Fetched).